# how to execute executable with arguments in nodejs and shutdown it

Tags: javascript, executable-jar, child-process

I have to run some commands like `./myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --kafka.topic=test --spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092` during running my javascript file.

My program is

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec(`./myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --kafka.topic=test --spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092`, function() {});
```

but it seems not working.

How to fix it? and how to shut it down in javascript?

any comments welcomed. Thanks

**UPDATE**

It seems that `exec(`./myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, [`--kafka.topic=test`,`--spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092`], function() {});` not working neither.

**UPDATE**

The following two working fine.

```
const child = require('child_process').spawn( 'bash', ['myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar', `--kafka.topic=test --spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092`]);
```

OR

```
const child = require('child_process').spawn( 'java', ['-jar', 'myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar', `--kafka.topic=test --spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092`]);
```

Comment: what operating system - how is it not working?

Comment: ubuntu. this depends on os?

Comment: You need to specify [callbacks](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to the exec command, to determine what went wrong.

Comment: @BAE, spawn worked for me  var child = require('child_process').spawn(
  'java', ['-jar', 'myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar', '--kafka.topic=test','--spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092`]
);

Comment: @NagaSaiA I got the error `TypeError: "options" argument must be an object`

Comment: can you try something like this  var child = require('child_process').spawn( 'java', ['-jar', 'myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar', {kafka.topic:test, spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers:localhost:9092}] )  passing arguments as object

Comment: @NagaSaiA not working

Comment: @BAE, is it working now , or any errors while using options as object